# Nextjs middleware redirect not working properly

Tags: caching, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I have a Next.js middleware that makes an API call to the server to check at what stage the access of the user is. Based on that it redirects the user to the relevant page. According to me it's a caching problem because when I reload the page, then the middleware runs correctly but when I change the access level from backend and do `route.push()` it does not redirect to the relevant page however it does show me that it is inside that `if` condition which it is supposed to be in.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

const fetchUserAccess = async (token: string) => {
const response = await fetch(
`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/user/access`,
{
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
}
)
return (await response.json()).data
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
const url = request.nextUrl.pathname
const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
const token = request.cookies.get('token')?.value
if (pathname.startsWith('/_next')) return NextResponse.next()
if (token !== undefined) {
if (url === '/login') {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/abc', request.url))
} else {
  const userAccess = await fetchUserAccess(token)
  if (userAccess === 'getstarted' && url !== '/getstarted') {
   
    request.nextUrl.pathname = '/getstarted'
    return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl)
  } else if (userAccess === 'abc' && url !== '/abc') {
   
    request.nextUrl.pathname = '/abc'
    return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl)
  } else if (userAccess === 'package' && url !== '/package') {
    
    request.nextUrl.pathname = '/package'
    return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl)
  }
}
} else {
if (url === '/abc' || url === '/getstarted' || url === '/history') {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
}
}
}

export const config = {
matcher: ['/abc', '/getstarted', '/package', '/login']
}
```

I tried adding cache headers like no-store, must-revalidate but the problem doesn't seem to go away. It shows me that it is inside `abc` if but it does not redirect. I expect it to be running on every route change. I am trying to protect my routes. In Next.js, I have tried using `useEffect`, `getServerSideProps` and now I am trying to use `middleware` to protect routes but each of these have forced me to use other method which results in other problems. If you know any other way to protect routes without caching problem or any other problem that may occur later on down the road then please let me know.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?